# Batch: Overwrite all files with 7zip?

Tags: batch-file, overwrite, 7zip

How can I overwrite all files when extraing a .zip using the 7zip command line?

I've tried with the -aoa switch but it didn't work.

What I currently have:

```
7za x -bd -r -y -o.. ../tmp/test.zip > log.txt
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and what is the problem?This command works for me.

Answer (score 2):

lets try this:

7za x  -o<..\tmp\test> -aoa

it does works for me.